# How to rotate image in elliptical form without rotating the image CSS

Tags: html, css, image-rotation

I have a [jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nNDkU/49/) in which I am rotating an image in an elliptical form. However, I do not want the image to rotate at the same time.

To correct this, I set the rotational `-webkit-keyframes mO` with the following properties:

```
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); rotate(0deg);   }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); rotate(-360deg); }
```

Because in past attempts to get an elliptical rotation, setting the opposite rotational property stopped the circle from rotating. In this case, it is not working. Is there another way that I can get the image to not rotate throughout the path? This is my first project designing something for the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.deform  {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(3);
background-color: lightblue;
left: 270px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.rotate {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation: circle 10s infinite linear;    
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.counterrotate {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
-webkit-animation: ccircle 10s infinite linear;    
}

.inner {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-color: red;
display: block;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0.33);
 }

@-webkit-keyframes circle {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes ccircle {
from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)}
}
```

[**Check here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/5w3bE/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=5w3bE)

[image]

Comment: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/

Comment: thank you. I've seen both of those sources and that's where I've based my inference on. Unfortunately, those are both circles and not ellipses.

Comment: is there a way to do this without deforming the image?

Comment: First one is pure eclipse

Comment: but the square is blurry. i need this ellipse for a picture, so I can't have it be blurry.

Comment: yes. if you even look at your jfiddle, the square is burry there.

Comment: thank you sir. I will accept the answer if you can post one that is not blurry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117835/discussion-between-ranjan-satpathy-and-nick-predey).

Comment: is there a way to make the path elliptical but not have it affect the image? like to make them independent of each other?